# Using link-to to call action from a different controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to use `link-to` or `action` in Ember JS to call an action from a different controller?

I am trying to create a sign out link that appeas on different templates, but all of these templates will have different controllers. The sign out logic will live in `SessionController`....

I am thinking of something like

`{{link-to 'sign_out' controller='session'}}Sign out{{/link-to}}`

or

`<a {{action 'sign_out' controller='session'}}>Sign out</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would let it bubble up to my application route, then use `controllerFor` to get the instance of the session controller then send it the action `sign_out`.

Bubbling: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    sign_out: function(){
      var session = this.controllerFor('session');
      session.send('sign_out');
    }
  }
});

<button {{action 'sign_out'}}> Sign Out</button>
```

Comment: And after sending the action you can transition to index or any other page with `this.transitionTo('index')`

Comment: Thanks... this is what I ended up doing as well.